# Does dilution of company increase its networth?

Tags: stock-market

Let's say a company has 1 million shares and its net worth is 10 million dollars. So each share has an intrinsic value of 10 USD.

Now lets say the company introduces 100 thousand shares and sells each for a valie of 5 USD. So the company gains 500K USD.

Now this money is added to the previous networth of the company making it 10.5 million dollars.

So diluting a company's equity increases it's networth?

Comment: Why are those original shares still worth $10?

Comment: Assuming the traded value is same as implicit value

Comment: Share's are fungible so nobody would buy shares for \$10 if they could buy them for \$5.

Comment: @RobertLongson No no, the actual value before is 10, but while diluting it only then it is sold at 5. Look at what Twitter is doing.